# How to map network shares at login on server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, mapping

I am trying to map a couple network shares for anyone who logs in to the domain under their AD credentials.  I had this setup before, and now I can't get it to work at all... so frustrating.

I'm trying putting the logon script under the user's profile, putting the logon script under the Group Policy Object logon script section.

Please help, none of the network shares are being mounted.

Comment: The problem turned out to be that the share was on a server that wasn't cooperating with the AD server in some way. I really don't know enough to explain what was going on.  Needless to say, restarting said server fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of places this could go wrong, so let's start with some basics.

1. What group policy did you add this to?
2. Have you run the GPMC from the workstation and account of a user, reviewed the GPresults, and verified that the proper GPOs and setting are taking effect as you want them to?
3. Can the user reach and run the script (in the location you've specified, should be a network share usually) from a normal command prompt? If they can't run the script, that's a problem.
4. If they can run the script, does it do what you expect - does it map the drive?

Comment: I'm adding my own explanation to the problem as a comment, but I feel this answer offers the most pertinent information for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually run the script as the logged in user, do the shares get mounted?

Answer (score 0):

What clients are you using? If it is windows 7 you may have an issue running VB scripts with UAC.